# Angular 12 - leaflet : leaflet routing maching problem - Property 'Routing' does not exist on type 'typeof import

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet

I hope you all good.
Im trying to use **leaflet routing maching** but i dnt know whats the problem.

**Steps i already do it :**

1. npm install --save leaflet-routing-machine
2. dashboard.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-routing-machine';
import "leaflet-routing-machine/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.css";
import {Poste} from "@/Model/Poste";
import {PosteService} from "@services/poste.service";
import {HttpErrorResponse} from "@angular/common/http";
import {SharedDataService} from "@services/shared-data.service";
import {ToastrService} from "ngx-toastr";

// default icon (blue)
let iconDefault = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'assets/marker-icon.png',
  shadowUrl: 'assets/marker-shadow.png',

  iconSize:     [25, 41], // size of the icon
  shadowSize:   [41, 41], // size of the shadow
  iconAnchor:   [12, 41], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
  shadowAnchor: [12, 41],  // the same for the shadow
  popupAnchor:  [1, -34] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
// red icon
let redIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'assets/marker-icon-red.png',
  shadowUrl: 'assets/marker-shadow.png',

  iconSize:     [25, 41], // size of the icon
  shadowSize:   [41, 41], // size of the shadow
  iconAnchor:   [12, 41], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
  shadowAnchor: [12, 41],  // the same for the shadow
  popupAnchor:  [1, -34] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
// user icon
let userIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'https://assets.mapquestapi.com/icon/v2/flag-Moi-3B5998-22407F-lg.png',
  popupAnchor:  [1, -34] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});


@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard',
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})

export class DashboardComponent {
  public postes: Poste[];
    public map;
    public posteInfo : Poste;
  public delegations: number[];
  public selectedDeleg: number;
  public markerGroup;
  public rangeValues: number[] = [0,100];



  constructor(private posteService: PosteService,private sharedDataService:SharedDataService,
              private toastr: ToastrService) {
    this.selectedDeleg=0;
  }


  createMap(){
        const Casablanca = {
            lat : 33.5731104,
            lng : -7.5898434
        };

        const ZoomLevel = 12;
        this.map = L.map('map',{
            center: [Casablanca.lat, Casablanca.lng],
            zoom: ZoomLevel
        });

        const mainLayer = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          minZoom: 11,
          maxZoom: 17,
          attribution: '&copy; Carte LYDEC '
        });
        mainLayer.addTo(this.map);
        this.getPostes();
    }

// ERROR 
  L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
      L.latLng(57.74, 11.94),
      L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)
    ]
  }).addTo(this.map);


}
```

**ERROR**

> TS2339: Property 'Routing' does not exist on type 'typeof import("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/EHTP GI/EHTP 2_GI 2020-2021/Stage ing\u00E9nieur/Stage Lydec 2021/Projet/Console_FrontEnd/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index")'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place `L.Routing` part in the method instead of global.

```js
export class DashboardComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ...

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.createMap();

    L.Routing.control({
      waypoints: [
        L.latLng(57.74, 11.94),
        L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)
      ]
    }).addTo(this.map);
  }
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-smevxo)

---

### Reference

[How To Build Maps in Angular with Leaflet, Part 1: Generating Maps](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-angular-and-leaflet)